# How to know when I would get any profit by Monero mining program?

Tags: monerod, monero-wallet-gui, mining, mining-pools, mining-theory

I am an absolutely newb to Monero and Blockchain.

I download the Monero GUI program from https://getmonero.org/downloads/ and run on my windows system.

After sync all block to my local, I started to mine by click the mining btn in advanced tab.

The program shows that the speed of mining is 200H/s, but I have not got any Monero coin so far.

I want to know when I would get any profit?

If I pause the mining and change some config, then continue mining, is there any negative influence on mining?

Answer (score 2):

The current difficulty of the network is approximately 125 billion, meaning that on average you need to calculate 125 billion hashes to find a block. At 200 hashes per second, you can expect to find a block in 125,000,000,000 / 200 = 625 million seconds. That's 20 years.

Now of course you could get lucky and find a block on your first hash but the probability of that happening is extremely low.

You would probably be better off mining to a pool - if you find a pool with a minimum payment of 0.01 XMR, you could expect to receive 0.01 XMR in about 15 days (your difficulty for that payment will be 125 billion x 0.01 XMR / 5.15 XMR, where 5.15 is the average current block reward).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, is there any good way to learn main theory about block chain and monero? It is easy for me to download and install some program but it is hard to understand all the technical under this program.

Comment: Sorry I meant 15 days, not weeks. You can find some answers on the official website. If you want the got details you can read the cryptonote white paper and the MRL papers.

Answer (score 1):

By solo mining of course you could get lucky and find a block below the average 125 bln hases, but the same way you could find it well over the average and get the block at say 200 bln hashes solved or so....
I actually believe that these days, a reasonable hash power to think about solo mine with monero in a profitable perspective, should be not less than 30-40 kH/s that should give a block find every 1-2 months.
Solo mining, thus running a full node, however, is a good way to support the strength of the monero network, that's anyway good in a macro perspective, if you own some moneros or simply trust the project.

Answer (score 0):

You will be better off mining at a pool.  xmr-stak is a decent mining program.
Plenty of guides and most pools will have guides.

If mining from a standard computer don't expect much profits.

But with solo mining from the GUI/CLI any profits will show in the balance.  A block is worth a bit over 5mxr right now.  But finding one solo a standard desktop will be a lottery ticket.

Config change pauses won't have any measurable impact.

Comment: Thank you,  I have installed it and run,  can I know how long can I get any profit? Because for some hours my wallet is 0 all the time.

Comment: At 200 H/s quick calc is .001 xmr a day.  Mining Aeon (xmr-stak will) might be a better option and then convert)